# What is the point of .decode()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> infile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.yahoo.com")
```

**With decoding:**

```
>>>infile.read(100).decode()

'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en-US" class="dev-desktop uni-purple-border  bkt901 https  uni-dark-purp'
```

**Without decoding:**

```
>>>infile.read(100)

b'le" style="">\n<!-- m2 template  -->\n<head>\n    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; c'
```

It appears the difference is the `'b` before the output, which I assume means bytes. Besides that, the output is exactly the same though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the output is not the same; one is a Unicode value, the other an undecoded bytes value.

For ASCII, that *looks* the same, but when you load any web page that uses characters outside the ASCII characterset, the difference will be much clearer.

Take UTF-8 encoded data, for example:

```
>>> '–'
'–'
>>> '–'.encode('utf8')
b'\xe2\x80\x93'
```

That's a simple [U+2013 EN DASH](http://codepoints.net/U+2013) character. The bytes representation shows the 3 bytes UTF-8 uses to encode the codepoint.

You really want to read up on Unicode vs. encoded data here, I recommend:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder